# Difference between Spring provided starter projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning `Spring boot`.

There are many starter projects provided. From a developer point of view, what is the difference amongst all of them, when should one go one specifically?

For instances, what is difference in - `spring-boot-starter-parent`,`spring-boot-starter-web`,`spring-boot-starter-freemarker`,`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Spring starter's documentation.

> Spring Boot Starters are a set of convenient dependency descriptors
>   that you can include in your application. You get a one-stop-shop for
>   all the Spring and related technology that you need without having to
>   hunt through sample code and copy paste loads of dependency
>   descriptors. For example, if you want to get started using Spring and
>   JPA for database access just include the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
>   dependency in your project, and you are good to go.

Refer [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-starters) for all starter-poms supported by spring.

1. **spring-boot-starter-web**  - Starter for building web, including RESTful, applications using Spring MVC. Uses Tomcat as the default embedded container
2. **spring-boot-starter-freemarker** - Starter for building MVC web applications using FreeMarker views
3. **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa** - Starter for using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate

Refer [spring's official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter) for more starter-projects.

Starters provide you OOTB integration of different applications shunning the need of boilerplate configuration.

Hope this helps!